# Need Twilio Call Summary

Tags: twilio

I have a scenario to make a call through  twilio. When I call the twilio, it gives me multiple options to connect just like a conventional IVR. Then I select a specific contact to through my call, Twilio makes me connected to the selected contact successfully. When I fetch the call duration, it returns me the whole time span, from IVR start to call ending.

Is there any option to fetch the call duration of the call with selected person.
Please reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure.  It sounds like your probably using the `<Dial>` verb to dial a number number from your IVR.  In that case you can use the [action parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) of that verb.

The URL set in the action parameter will be requested when the person you `<Dial>`ed ends the call.  In that request, Twilio includes a few extra parameters, including one called DialCallDuration:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-parameters

Hope that helps.